# Problems deleting items from Redux store using onClick event

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

I want to be able to delete an specific object from an array in my `store`. I made a delete item function that works and deletes the objects, however I haven't been able to figure out how to make this function work when I use a button that is rendered with each object with `map`. This is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {addCart} from './Shop';
import { removeCart } from '../../actions'; 
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class Cart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {items: this.props.cart,cart: [],total: 0};
    }

    handleClick(item) {
        this.props.onCartRemove(item);
    } 

    ...


    render() {
        return(
            <div className= "Webcart" id="Webcart">
                <div>
                    {this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
                        return <li className='cartItems' key={'cartItems_'+index}>
                            <h4>{item.item}</h4>
                            <p>Size: {item.size}</p>
                            <p>Price: {item.price}</p>
                            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Remove</button>
                        </li>
})}
                </div>
                <div>Total: ${this.countTotal()}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onCartAdd: (cart) => {
            dispatch(addCart(cart));
        },
        onCartRemove: (item) => {
            dispatch(removeCart(item));
        },
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { cart: state.cart };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Cart);
```

With the function `handleClick` I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null`. If I try something like

```
deleteItem() {
        return this.state.items.reduce((acc, item) => {
            return this.props.onCartRemove(item);
        })
    }
```

... the code deletes all items in the loop without any errors. How can I can use the button to remove that particular item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you really getting the item for it to be removed?

try this on your button inside your map:

```
<button onClick={() => this.handleClick(item)}>Remove</button>
```

Comment: did this solve the question? if so, please consider an upvote for others to see the best and the accepted answers, don't be shy to upvote others even if it isnt the correct answer but if they are providing helpful insights that made you move closer to your goal.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind your handler.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {items: this.props.cart,cart: [],total: 0};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
```

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html